# Xamarin android web view showing 403 forbidden in Android kit-kat 4.4 devices

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, http-status-code-403, android-4.4-kitkat

I have made an android app on xamarin platform, I have some buttons and a web view and I am rendering website URLs on every button clicks.

My app works very well on android version more than 4.4 ( I have tried many times on android 5 and above)
web sites are rendering nicely as well as in emulator and other devices too.

But when I try to run it on KitKat I got this message on web view:
403 forbidden nginx

Here is the screenshot: [screenshot of webview on android 4.4 kikat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Z76.png)

Here is my web view code:

```
    <android.webkit.WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
```

Here is my android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="10" android:versionName="1.02" package="com.patientpoint.ptcoa" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo_new"></application>
```

Here is main activity to render webview: `  webView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.webView1);
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new ExtendWebViewClient());

```
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.Settings;
        webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webSettings.SetSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        webSettings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
        webSettings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
        webSettings.UseWideViewPort = true;

        webView.LoadUrl(ConstantUrl.HomeUrl);
```

`

Screenshot of Android Manifest: [Android Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E3as.png)

Screenshot of android options :[Android Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMmaJ.png)

Please tell me what should I do to remove 403 and render my website in android 4.4.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: problem with back-end. check ssl and tls for server.

Comment: How can I check Kuldip please suggest me

Comment: enter you domain here https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html and check its have all certificated added properly or not.

Comment: this one have better results https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: Kuldip Sir, That website which is I am trying to render is not mine. That web site renders very fine in chrome.

Comment: that's doesn't mean its work in android too.

Comment: try to open that website in kitkat crome browser

Comment: yeah, works fine, but not in phone's inbuilt browser

Comment: Make sure that  if your code can work on the higher version of Android (like Android 8.0,8.1 and 9.0). The version of your device is too low , which will maybe raises some unknown issues.